# CSS translateX(100%) on <input> in a parent with overflow causes 'flickering' and inconsistent width

Tags: html, css, css-animations, transform

**What i'm trying to achieve**

[example of the closed version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahiJT.png) /
[example of the opened version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DdgA.png)

At the top of the page in a 'fixed' header, i have a 'search' button next to a 'toggle' for the main menu. The header-search div (magnifying glass) is positioned next to the menu toggler (green). A form is currently positioned 'absolute' within the header to take up the full width of the header minus the padding on each side and its controls (search and toggler) as follows:

styles from header

```
.header {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: var(--color-primary-700);
}
```

styles from header__aux

```
.header__aux {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 1rem;
  flex-flow: nowrap row;
}

.header-search {
  display: block;
  position: static;
}

.header-search__form {
  top: 1.5rem;
  height: 4rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: var(--g-gutter);
  width: calc(100% - (7rem + (var(--g-gutter)*2)));
}

.header-search__form-label {
  top: -99.9rem;
  left: -99.9rem;
  color: inherit;
  position: absolute;
}

.header-search__form.is-active
.header-search__form-input {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.header-search__form-input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4rem;
  padding: 0 1.2em;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  border: .2rem solid #8097b3;
  border-top-left-radius: 2rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 2rem;
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out
  background-color: var(--color-primary-700);
}
```

A input field inside this form is given 100% width and then using transform: translateX(100%) pushed completely to the right outside the overflow of the form (which retains it's width as set above). When a user presses the 'search' button a class is-active sets this transform: translateX(100%) to 0 and the input field should slide (from the right) to it's original position 100% of the width as seen in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcJcO.png).

**What this looks like in HTML**

```
    <header class="header section">
        <div class="header__container container">
    
                    <a class="header__brand" href="#" aria-label="x">
               <!-- svg brand -->
            </a>
    
                    <div class="header__navs" id="headerNavs">
                <div class="header__mask">
    
                    <ul id="headerMenu" class="header-menu">
</ul> <div class="header__langs header-langs">
                        Language
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    
    
                    <div class="header__aux">
                <div class="header__search header-search">
                    <button aria-label="Open of sluit het invoerveld voor een zoekopdracht" class="header-search__toggle" id="headerSearchToggle" aria-pressed="false" role="button" tabindex="0">
                        <i id="headerSearchIcon" class="far fa-search"></i>
                    </button>
    
                    <form class="header-search__form" action="/" id="headerSearchForm" role="search" method="get">
    
                        <label class="header-search__form-label" for="headerSearchInput">Zoeken</label>
                        <div class="header-search__form-slide">
                            <input placeholder="Zoeken …" required="" class="header-search__form-input" id="headerSearchInput" minlength="2" type="search" value="" name="s">
    
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
    
                <a aria-label="" class="header__toggle header-toggle" aria-controls="headerNavs" aria-expanded="false" id="headerToggle" href="#">
    
                    Toggle
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

**The problem**

When opening the 'search' the input immediately jumps to the end of the animation which is seen in the **example of the opened version (top)** and then continues moving left, constantly correcting it's position back to what is seen in the image causing a weird 'flickering' effect [usually in this position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAAfj.png). Sliding the input 'back' to the right works perfectly.. What's even weirder is that it sometimes **does** work correctly for a few attempts once i've been on the page for a while. Then suddenly it breaks again.

**What i've tried**

- Different types of browsers, including checking it on my own mobile device (not in the dev tools)
- Giving the input the same fixed width as the parent
- Removing a translateY on the parent and reverting to 'top' top position it in the vertical center
- Adding 1 or multiple parents to the input to force it to inherit that width
- As mentioned in a comment, adding transform:translateZ(0.1px); to force rendering using the GPU

**What works, but i can't explain**

Removing the overflow on the parent form element works and allows the animation to play smoothly, but that shows the input behind the element [as seen in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VxTy.png)

I can think of some ways to make this look better, but i just really want to know what i'm missing. I believe i've done these types of simple animations 1000s of times now. A parent with overflow, hiding a child that's translated over.. or perhaps i'm mistaken. Hopefully someone can make sense of this - many thanks if you've taken the time to do so :)

Comment: Could you show us a slightly more complete code set - especially what the CSS is as I may have misinterpreted 'transform: translateX(100%) to 0'. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AHaworth Sorry, i added some additional code. It may not be sufficient - i'm not on the right machine currently so i could copy it over that easily :(

Comment: Welcome to SO that's a very well-asked question. Have you tried adding a parent element to the input and transitioning the parent instead of the input itself? Inputs are odd elements in that they have one foot in the system and one foot in the browser. I also suggest adding a Z transform (transform:translateZ(0.1px);) as this will force the GPU to help out with rendering.  Remember to combine that Z transform with your other existing transforms :-)

Comment: @BryceHowitson Hi!, thanks for the suggestions - i forgot to include the 'translateZ' trick in the 'what i tried' list (sorry) but that sadly didn't seem to work. I also tried 1 or multiple parent elements and that didn't seem to work either. I actually edited the html code with the version including this 'slide' div with class .header-search__form-slide (by accident) earlier.

Comment: Bummer. Can you maybe use the javascript/html/css snippet button to create a working example? Should be pretty easy since you've got all the code currently. That will give us a "run" button so we can try to replicate the issues and actually see what's going on with some developer tools.

Comment: in your latast line of css code in `transition: transform 1s ease-in-out` you forget a `;`. Did you notice that?

Comment: @M.RMRF Thank you, i didn't notice that in the code i pasted but it is present in the actual file. I wasn't on the right machine at the time so i copied that part over from the browser dev tools which may explain that error :)